# Detect error on transaction with psql script on ansible

Tags: postgresql, ansible

We have the following script (script.sql):

```
BEGIN;
SET client_min_messages = warning;

\COPY foo_table FROM 'foo.csv' csv header DELIMITER ';';
\COPY bar_table FROM 'bar.csv' csv header DELIMITER ';';

COMMIT;
```

We launch this script in an ansible playbook with

community.postgresql.postgresql_db

```
- name: 'Restore SQL dump(s) on database(s)'
  become: yes
  become_user: 'postgres'
  postgresql_db:
    name: 'db'
    target: 'script.sql'
    state: 'restore'
```

How can we detect if the transaction fail with a rollback to get an error on the deployment ?

Comment: Best bet for something like this is to check `man psql` or read the comprehensive online docs. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#id-1.9.4.20.7

Answer (score 0):

The common way is to use `-v ON_ERROR_STOP=on` on psql command line, or alternatively `\set ON_ERROR_STOP on` in the SQL script.

According to the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html):

> **ON_ERROR_STOP**
>
> By default, command processing continues after an error. When this
> variable is set to on, **processing will instead stop immediately**. In
> interactive mode, psql will return to the command prompt; otherwise,
> psql will exit, returning error code 3 to distinguish this case from
> fatal error conditions, which are reported using error code 1. In
> either case, any currently running scripts (the top-level script, if
> any, and any other scripts which it may have in invoked) will be
> terminated immediately. If the top-level command string contained
> multiple SQL commands, processing will stop with the current command.